# Admob background always black

Tags: android, colors, background, admob

In Admob website i created an ad with blue background, but in my ap background comes black.
I tried adding colors manually in my code, but ad background is always black.

Help me please. Thank you.

Main Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toPhone = R.drawable.wall1;
    AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
    AdMobAdapterExtras extras = new AdMobAdapterExtras()
    .addExtra("color_bg", "6D0504")
    .addExtra("color_bg_top", "6D0504")
    .addExtra("color_border", "6D0504")
    .addExtra("color_link", "000080")
    .addExtra("color_text", "808080")
    .addExtra("color_url", "008000");

    AdRequest adreq = new AdRequest();
    adreq.setNetworkExtras(extras);
    adview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#128cff"));
    adview.loadAd(adreq);
```

Main Layout

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/ad"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"  
android:background="#128cff"
ads:background="#6D0504"
android:gravity="center" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="app.technozed.ios7stylehdwallpapers"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
     >
     <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name="app.technozed.ios7stylehdwallpapers.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Check your ad settings in admob dashboard. You need to have this enabled "Use colors set in client code".

Comment: @Tarun this is what i set in AdMob
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7i3cniyam4g1wd/admob.png

Answer (score 1):

The config you applied in the Admob dashboard only applies to text based ads.

Image based ads will have their own background which you will not be able to change.

Comment: in my apps i have the same black background for both, images banners and text banners. i changed colors in admob options . . .